# How to customize the ContentPage Title in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, uwp

In Xamarin UWP phone view, content page title font size is too big.How to customize the page title font size in the Windows phone?

Thanks,
Santhiya A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the Xamarin.Forms [`PageControlStyle`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/PageControlStyle.xaml#L23) before customizing the page title font size.

```
<uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
    <Border x:Name="TitleArea" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TitleVisibility}" Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding TitleBrush}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Border>
</uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
```

As you can see, the title of ContentPage was rendered by `TextBlock` within uwp platform, and the style of `TextBlock` was [`TitleTextBlockStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources). So you could change the tile font size by modifying the [`TitleTextBlockStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources).

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style
             x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
             <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight" />
             <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
             <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
         </Style>
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Is PageControl is related to ContentPage? Sorry, i can't get it, how to use it ? In my requirement is to change the PageTitle default font size.

Comment: Yes. they are related. You could only place the `TitleTextBlockStyle`  in the App.xaml  file within uwp client project. The font size of title will be effect.

Comment: Is it possible to apply a style only for WindowsPhone?

Comment: Zhu Any idea about this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708474/scrollview-not-working-on-touch-in-xamarin-uwp?noredirect=1#comment74466919_43708474

Comment: I think you missed the `uwp` tag for the case you mentioned.